# Exiting if statement without exiting sub

Tags: vba, if-statement, exit

I have a VBA code that removes empty cells, allowing for data further down in the column to move up to the top.  There are two things that I am looking to fix.  One, I don't want to exit the sub, I want to exit the if statement.  I've read that you can exit loops, whiles, fors, etc. But not ifs.  I don't want to exit the sub because I have more code in my sub.  Any suggestions?

I am also having issues adding another line in the code to run if there is already data at the top of the column.

```
    Sub Remove_Empties ()

    Dim Last as Long
    Dim Mcol as Range

    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "AD").End(xlUp).Row
    If Last = 1 Then Exit Sub 'no value only header in row 1
    'otherwise
    Set Mcol = Range("AD2:AD" & Last) 'contains any value
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Mcol.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlUp
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

I want it to be able to run the following three scenarios.  The first contains data in the row below the header.  The second has a couple of empty cells.  The third has all empty cells.  1 should not change, 2 should change to match 1's format, and 3 should do nothing. 2 and 3 can be done with the code above, but not 1.

```
    1         2         3
    A       
    B  
    C         A
    D         B
              C
              D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this, noting the following:

- You don't need *two* `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` lines. You can probably get rid of both.
- You need to handle the possibility of no blank cells (column 1).

---

```
Sub Remove_Empties()

    Dim Last As Long
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "AD").End(xlUp).Row

    If Last <> 1 Then
        Dim Mcol As Range
        Set Mcol = Range("AD2:AD" & Last) 'contains any value

        Dim cellsToDelete As Range

        On Error Resume Next
        Set cellsToDelete = Mcol.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not cellsToDelete Is Nothing Then
            cellsToDelete.Delete shift:=xlUp
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Or slightly condensed:

```
Sub Remove_Empties()

    Dim Last As Long
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "AD").End(xlUp).Row

    If Last <> 1 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Range("AD2:AD" & Last).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        On Error GoTo 0 
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That works great.  Thank you!  What does `<>` mean?

Comment: It means "does not equal."

Answer (score 0):

I will just add another answer that you can possibly use in your logic (code) moving forward. Using a simple `GoTo` statement will break out of an `If`. For example:

```
Sub UsingGoTo()

    If Last = 1 Then
        'do something
        GoTo CheckComplete
    Else
        'if not maybe exit sub?
        Exit Sub
    End If

CheckComplete:
    'continue with program

End Sub
```